# Routed traffic away from VPN has no internet (Fedora)

Tags: vpn, ip, openvpn, fedora, route

I'm very new to linux routing and such as a preface.  I have a plex server set up on Fedora 22. I've recently started using a VPN service connected via OpenVPN.  Everything works great via VPN on my internal network but of course externally my Plex server has stopped publishing.  I read somewhere about adding routing entries for plex.tv's services via IP to be routed through my router rather than my VPN tunnel.  So I added all of the IP's plex uses (found here: http://www.dnswatch.info/dns/dnslookup?la=en&host=plex.tv&type=A&submit=Resolve) via the following command

```
route add -net 184.169.156.178 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1
```

It appears as though traffic to plex.tv is trying to route through my router but it just drops off right after there.

```
traceroute plex.tv
traceroute to plex.tv (50.18.115.47), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  gateway (192.168.1.1)  0.238 ms  0.212 ms  0.245 ms
2  * * *
3  * * *
```

As opposed to traffic going to google.com

```
traceroute to google.com (216.58.219.238), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  10.174.1.1 (10.174.1.1)  47.522 ms  47.446 ms  47.448 ms
2  108.61.68.129 (108.61.68.129)  47.568 ms  47.687 ms  47.991 ms
```

I'm not sure why this is? My router has it's own OpenVPN server which assigns ip's on a different subnet 10.8.0.0 as opposed to 192.168.1.0, I added an entry for that subnet so I could VPN from work to home and SSH into my server and such and that works fine, not sure where to go from here to get just plex.tv traffic to not travel across the VPN

Comment: Your traffic to google is going through another gateway, look at the ip 10.174.1.1. Which device is this? What ip does your plex server has?

Comment: That's my VPN  gateway

`tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.174.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.174.1.5`

And my server's ip is 192.168.1.26

Comment: How many internet connection do you have? Have you tested if you can you reach plex.tv over your vpn tunnel?

Comment: I only have 1 but I have access to others (such as work and stuff).  My VPN doesn't do port forwarding so no, I'm not able to access it, at least not over the ports I need for it to work right.

Comment: Well, I didn't quite understand what you meant by port forwarding not allowed over vpn. You should be able to connect to any port over vpn. I guess you will need to provide more infos on your network infrastructure and connectivities if you need further help.

Comment: I guess ultimately port forwarding doesn't matter.  My end goal is to get this traffic to bypass the VPN so I shouldn't have to worry about port forwarding through the VPN at all

Comment: The information you have provided is insufficient to say something concrete. If you want to bypass vpn, you have to see that you can reach internet through gateway 192.168.1.1. See if you can reach some other external ip, i.e. 8.8.8.8 by setting static route. If you cant't then you have little chance.

Comment: And also post the entry that you added to reach the server from work. May be it can related to that also.

Answer (score 0):

The information you have provided is insufficient to say something concrete. But If you want to bypass vpn, you have to see that you can reach internet at all through gateway 192.168.1.1. At the moment it doesn't seems so.

From the given information, the traceroute to google is clearly passing through another gateway (see the first hop is 10.174.1.1, where is it set?). To test further, if you can reach some other external ip, you may set static route for google dns (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4) and see if it woks. If it doesn't then you have little chance.